# cohomology of curves

Tags: cohomology, sheaf-theory, curves

Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex curve. Consider the diagonal $\Delta$
in $X \times X$, and $\mathcal{O}(\Delta)$ the associated line bundle.
If $j$ is the inclusion of $\Delta$ in $X \times X$ and $TX$ is the tangent bundle to $X$,
there is a canonical map from $\mathcal{O}(\Delta)$ to $j_*(TX)$.
Is this map surjective? If not, what is the image?

Comment: It is surjective. For any line bundle $L$ on $X\times X$, the natural map $L\rightarrow j_*j^*L$ is surjective (just look locally). For $L=\mathcal{O}(\Delta )$, this is the map you consider.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
And what about the map from $p_*(\mathcal{O}(\Delta))$ to TX, where p is one projection from XxX to X?

Comment: This map is  zero.